# set scheduler programmatically in android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to set scheduler for the user for particular time with details like on 3'watch movie" even if the application is not open at that time.

Is there any way that i can get it done in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `AlarmManager` to display specific activities at a given time. The `AlarmManager` will make sure the activity or service if you like will be started even if the app is not open at the time and the `AlarmManager` is battery friendly as well

First of all you need to get the AlarmManager instance :

```
myAlarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

and then you can schedule an activity to be shown periodically or just once :

```
myAlarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, _whenToStart, _intervalIfAny, _PendingIntentToStartActivityOrService);
```

for more details see the documentation [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Thanks psicho for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the features of the BuzzBox SDK that is build on top of the AlarmManager and will give you some advanced features for scheduling recurring Tasks. You can use a cron string and you get a Settings activity so your users can change time, frequency, days of the week, etc.
See: http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/